# ¿Como poner una imagen dentro de floating button?

Tags: android

deseo introducir la foto de perfil de un usuario en el floating button, el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que despliega es de esta, forma pero quiero que se muestre sin ningún margen, osea que llene completamente el floating button

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas cargar una imagen que se encuentra en `/drawable`, puedes usar el método [setImageResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#setImageResource(int)) del [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html)

```
 myFloatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable/imagen);
```

Si deseas evitar que la imagen se muestre con "padding", puedes usar la propiedad  `app:borderWidth` y definir un borde de 0dp:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    ...
    ...
    app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```